JMeter: within JSR223 script get total number of samplers within a particular thread group
I have this JMeter test plan

How can get number of samplers within "Test 1 Thread Group" (3 in this particular example)?

Here is a full Java JSR223 sampler code to find out number of samplers in ThreadGroup with particular name:
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.AbstractSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController;

log.info("----------------------------------------------------");

String basePath = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
String jmxFile = basePath + File.separator + "test.jmx";
File file = new File(jmxFile);
HashTree tree = SaveService.loadTree(file);

static int getNumberOfSamplers(String threadGroupName) {
    for (Map.Entry entry : tree.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() instanceof TestPlan) {
            HashTree testplan = (HashTree) entry.getValue();

            for (Map.Entry element : testplan.entrySet()) {
                if (element.getKey() instanceof AbstractThreadGroup) {
                    AbstractThreadGroup myGroup = (AbstractThreadGroup) element.getKey();
                    if (myGroup.getName().equals(threadGroupName)) {
                        SearchByClass samplerSearch = new SearchByClass(AbstractSampler.class);
                        element.getValue().traverse(samplerSearch); // element.getValue() is ListedHashTree
                        return samplerSearch.getSearchResults().size();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
log.info(getNumberOfSamplers("Test 1 Thread Group").toString());
log.info(getNumberOfSamplers("Test 2 Thread Group").toString());


log.info("----------------------------------------------------");


I think this is not how StackOverflow works, you're supposed to try out something yourself, share what you've tried and the error you're getting if something doesn't work for you.
With regards to your question itself, your requirement is possible to implement here is the evidence:

And reference materials:

JMeter API
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
Building a Test Plan Programmatically


Can you please include in your answer groovy code from the screenvideo?
